# Alternative Match...Against FULL-TEXT

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

the previous question was based on the search results, the response I got to use the FULL-TEXT.

Now the question is, how to write it in a different way, not to use FULL-TEXT? There is a possibility?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/227312/1/0  The same effect, of course:

Comment: why are you trying to avoid Full-Text index/search? Do you have specific requirements to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a fulltext index of some kind, searches for words within text will cause a table-scan.

```
SELECT keywords FROM topic WHERE keywords LIKE '%Ruby New%';
```

or

```
SELECT keywords FROM topic WHERE keywords RLIKE '[[:<:]]Ruby New[[:>:]]';
```

These queries work, in that they return the same result. But they have performance **thousands of times slower** (or worse) than using a fulltext index. The performance disadvantage of using a table-scan depends on the size of your table.

I did a presentation about this: [Full Text Search Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql), comparing the performance of different text searching solutions.